# C# passing information

Tags: c#, t-sql, webforms

Sorry in advance im going to try and explain this as best as possible....

I have 2 asp.net pages one named membermaster and the second named memberdetails. I created a class library which contains 2 functions

My first function returns a list depending on the search result...

I added a linkbutton to the gridviews first column which when clicked it passes through querystring the membershipgen. What i wanted to do is for my second function i created this

```
public DataTable GetMembers(int MEMBERSHIPGEN)
{
  DataTable table = null;
  SqlConnection con = null;
  SqlCommand cmd = null;
  SqlDataAdapter ad = null;
  SqlParameter prm = null;
  try
  {
      table = new DataTable();
    using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_getmemberdetail", con))
        {
            using (ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                prm = new SqlParameter("@MEMBERSHIPGEN", SqlDbType.Int);
                prm.Value = MEMBERSHIPGEN;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
                ad.Fill(table);
            }

        }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
        //write your exception code here
  }
  return table;
}
```

In the attempt to try and send the membershipgen to this and it return the results. But once i compile the DLL and add it to my project I am not sure how i would reference this function to populate individual textboxes and labels with the information.

What I am trying to do is when a user clicks the viewdetails button on the gridview I can then use that membershipgen that I passed through querystring to populate the page through a stored procedure but the smarts would be stored in a DLL.

Comment: a bit off subject, but your `SqlConnection` should be wrapped in a `using` block as well.

Comment: when you say not sure how to reference..? are you meaning hot do you call the GetMembers() Method..? this is very simple to accomplish also are you using namespaces to to name your namespace within each class..? if you are not sure paste a small sample of both .cs files and I can update the header for you..

Comment: Your problem is that once GetMembers goes out of scope, table is destroyed which is where your results are. You would need to either change the method signature from void to something, perhaps DataTable or instead of populating a local variable, you'd populate a member/class variable.

Comment: I re-formatted your code to look more readable hope you can understand why I altered the using a bit...

Comment: Thanks Jeremy will update that...also DJ i have declared a namespace on the top of both .cs files Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change GetMembers to return data instead of void. If you want to use DataTables, you can just modify your code to this:

```
public DataTable GetMembers(int MEMBERSHIPGEN)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_getmemberdetail", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            SqlParameter prm = new SqlParameter("@MEMBERSHIPGEN", SqlDbType.Int);
            prm.Value = MEMBERSHIPGEN;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
            ad.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }
```

Then in your Page_Load it might be something like this (more robust than this hopefully):

```
{
    DataTable table = yourDll.GetMembers(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["membership"]));
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(table.rows[0]["Name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want your method to return a value.  Currently the return type is `void`, so the values it populates internally just go away when the call stack leaves the method.  It sounds like you want something like this:

```
public DataTable GetMembers(int MEMBERSHIPGEN)
```

Then, in your method, after you've populated the `DataTable` and exited the `using` blocks, you'd do something like this:

```
return table;
```

This would return the `DataTable` to whatever called the method.  So your page would have something like this:

```
DataTable table = GetMembers(membershipgen);
```

So the page would be responsible for:

- Get the `membershipgen` value from the input (query string)
- Call the method and get the result of the method
- Display the result from the method (bind to a grid? or whatever you're doing to display the data)

And the method is responsible for:

- Interact with the database

This is a good first step toward the overall goal of "[separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)" which is a very good thing to do.  You can continue down this path by always asking yourself what each method, class, etc. *should* be responsible for.  For example, your `GetMembers` method should also be responsible for ensuring that the value passed to it is valid, or that the value returned from it is not `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the response I went ahead and made those changes However I am still a little noobish on how to pass the membershipgen to the method within the DLL I created and how to retrieve the results from my datatable and populate individual textboxes with the results. Any help would be appreciated Also thanks for the link you posted will read that tonight when i get home...

Comment: @JawaidAkhtar: It sounds like you'll want to begin with some tutorials and walk-throughs. What you're talking about now is kind of outside the scope of the question, as well as bordering on general teaching and mentoring, which isn't really easy to do with a few comments.  You can start a new question about getting the value into the method, for example.  It's a beginner question, but if it's presented well then that's fine.  Where does the value come from?  How does it get sent to the page?  From there, we can show you how to send it to the method.  And so on.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go might be to construct the button so that it navigates to a url along the lines of:

http://localhost/DetailPage.aspx?membershipgen=4

Then in the load of the DetailPage.aspx:

```
Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostback)
    {
        int membershipgen;        

        if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["membershipgen"], out membershipgen)
        {
            //Get the data (replace DataAccess with the name of your data access class).
            //Also, you probably want to change GetMembers so it returns the data.
            DataTable table = DataAccess.GetMembers(membershipgen);

            //TODO: Display the results
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Display an error
    }
}
```